# publish_post action hook doesn't give post_meta_data

Tags: post-meta

I write the following function to get the post data on publish post but i see that post_meta is not available, its always empty. How do i retrieve the post meta data of a post on publish_post hook?

The bottom line is i want to collect the data $article convert into json and post it using curl. When i convert it using `print_r(json_encode($article))` it actually executes the html tags in the content and outputting. Is there any neat way to do it like how wp_send_json is doing?

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'newdb',10,2);

function newdb($post_id, $post){

            if($post_id !=null){
            $article['postID'] = $post->ID;
            $article['seo_url'] = get_permalink($post->ID);
            $article['title'] = $post->post_title;
            $article['status'] = $post->post_status;
            $article['body'] = html_entity_decode(htmlentities(addslashes($post->post_content)));
            $article['related'] = array();
            $relatedStories = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'realtor_related_stories', true);
            if ($relatedStories != null) {
                $rsCount = count($relatedStories) - 1;
                while ($rsCount > 0) {
                    $rStories['title'] = $relatedStories['related_stories_attribution_' . $rsCount]['headline'];
                    $rStories['seo_url'] = $relatedStories['related_stories_attribution_' . $rsCount]['url'];
                    $rStories['img_src'] = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(url_to_postid($rStories['seo_url'])));
                    array_push($article['related'], $rStories);
                    $rsCount--;
                }
            }
 $article['seo_focus_keyword'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', true);
            $article['seo_title'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);
            $article['seo_metadesc'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true);
  wp_send_json($article);
//print_r($article) => gives wierd output because of embed tags in post body

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the [`wp_send_json()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/) function is sending the right data, but for some reason you want to use another function to actually send the JSON data, then you can use [`wp_json_encode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/). This is basically the only thing that `wp_send_json()` does before sending off the data.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'wpse_228607_publish_post', 10, 2 );
function wpse_228607_publish_post( $post_id, $post ){
  //* Do some stuff to get your $article variable

  $encode = wp_json_encode( $article );

  //* Do some stuff with the json encoded article
}
```

Make sure you're sending the correct Content-Type and charset. `wp_send_json()` takes care of that for you.